# using tabs with jQuery - Clear tab content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm using jquery tabs in my web application. The tabs are created dynamically depending on the user query result. I have a couple issues:

1. My tab is pointing to `<div>` content with the corresponding id. When the user clicks the tab, the content is filled with a result of a webservice request (not relevant to the issue). My first problem is that when I add the items inside the tab (`<div>` tags), I see that it's not being placed *inside* the panel of the tab. I'm using `selectedTab.append("<div class=itemSummary>" + getItemDetails(element) + "</div>")` to add a new `<div>` section to the tab. However, I do see new items being added *outside* the border of the tab panel. Am I doing something wrong here?
2. Simple question: how can I programmatically clear the tab content? I need the tab content to be cleared before I add new items to it.

Thanks!

Comment: my current selected tab, i.e : $('#tabs')

Comment: You need to provide more code! When content is not displaying inside the borders of the Tabs, it's either CSS issue where content is overflowing in absolute position or content is being placed right outside of the Tab content container but before next Tab contents. Best way to clear content and load new inside the tab panel would be to use something like `selectedTab.html(VarWithHTMLcontent);` and make sure to store new content into the content variable before you call this line. This line will replace all inside content with whatever is stored in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

simple, use the $.empty(); function on the container that own the content .